# Why always shows the error missing 1 required positional argument: 'sqlQuery' while using pyspark SQLContext.sql()?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

As title mentioned, I tried to used SQL in pyspark to manipulate data in MySQL. But I am not sure why I have already set the query as follow, but always shows the error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'sqlQuery'". Is there someone have any idea about this issue, and can share the solution with me? I will be really appreciate. Thanks.

```
url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db'

df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table='test_data', properties=prop)

df.createTempView('example')

query = """SELECT * FROM example WHERE 'record date' BETWEEN '2020-09-05' AND '2020-09-18'"""

df2 = SQLContext.sql(query)

df2.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "missing 1 required positional argument: 'sqlQuery'" is because you're trying to call the method sql on the class SQLContext instead of an instance of it. To correct it, you need to create an instance of SQLContext and call sql on that instance:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
df2 = sqlContext.sql(query)
df2.collect()
```